# PGFPlots: adding points and managing the labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords, geogebra

I want to draw following with Tikz/PGFplots:

[image: The resulting plot]

X = 0:12. Y = 0:30.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{ududff}{rgb}{0.30196078431372547,0.30196078431372547,1}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0,0.39215686274509803,0}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
    domain=0:30,
    xmin=0, xmax=30,
    ymin=0, ymax=12,
    smooth,
    axis lines = left]
    \addplot[red] {1/25000*pow(x,4)-3/2500*pow(x,3)-3/200*pow(x,2)+1/2*x+7} node[above]{$f$};
    \addplot[black] {1/50000*pow(x,4)-11/5000*pow(x,3)+29/400*pow(x,2)-3/4*x+7} node[below]{$g$};
    
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

What needs to be added: the points B and C:

[image]

And if it is possible: removing the lines on the arrows + adding x and y above both axis. The $f$ and $g$ needs to be replaced somehow (would like them above the curves actually.

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another plot for the coordinates using a mark and `point meta=explicit symbolic` and `nodes near coords` to add "custom" labels to get:

[image]

Here is the modified MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{float}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[%
        domain=0:30,
        xmin=0, xmax=33,
        ymin=0, ymax=12,
        smooth,
        axis lines = left,
      ]
        \addplot[green] {1/25000*pow(x,4)-3/2500*pow(x,3)-3/200*pow(x,2)+1/2*x+7} node[above]{$f$};
        \addplot[blue] {1/50000*pow(x,4)-11/5000*pow(x,3)+29/400*pow(x,2)-3/4*x+7} node[below]{$g$};
        \addplot [
          only marks,
          mark=ball,
          mark size=2pt,
          point meta=explicit symbolic,
          nodes near coords
        ] coordinates {
            (10, 19/4) [B]
            (25, 7)    [C]
        };
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```